# Socket.io - Unable to send a message from client side to server side

Tags: jquery, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I have two files -

- index.html
- index.js

In **index.html**, I have a text box. I want to display the message typed on the text box on to the console (the command prompt of node.js).

[image]

In **index.html**, I wrote this -

```
<script>
  var socket = io();
  $('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });
</script>
```

On server side, in **index.js** I used this -

```
socket.on('chat message', function(msg){ //here is the listener to the event
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });
```

**But, the message is not getting displayed in the console. What's wrong with my code?** 
Please refer the below files, if needed.

**index.js**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });

socket.on('chat message', function(msg){ //here is the listener to the event
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });

});


http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
   //some code
    </style>
  </head>

  <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
  $('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });
</script>

  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you see anything printed on console?

Comment: Which console are you looking at, the browser console or the command line console?

Comment: @Gyandeep Yep, as you can see I'm also logging "user connected" and "user disconnected". I can see those messages whenever I connect and disconnect. But, when I type in a message and hit send, nothing is displayed.

Comment: @BidhanA The command line console of node.js

Comment: Try moving the `<script>` block in your html file that contains the socket.io code before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: @BidhanA Perfect! Thanks Bidhan, it worked. I think the body isn't loaded by the time the script is loaded. As you suggested,  moving it after the <body> worked. Thanks!

Comment: Please write the same as an answer, so that I can accept it! :)

Comment: You're welcome Nikhil. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `<script>` block in your html file that contains the socket.io code before the closing `</body>` tag so that the script is loaded only after the body completes loading.